# How to find max and min values regardless of being positive or negative using R

Tags: r, dplyr, max, min

I have a data frame that look like:

```
Genes   intA    Chr_intA    Chr_intB    direction_1 direction_2 distance
GeneA   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -423
GeneA   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -3467567
GeneA   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   10452
GeneB   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -2884
GeneB   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -40
```

I want to group by columns `Genes` and ``` intA`` and then only get rows with the maximum or minimum values (regardless of being positive or negative) in the last column called ``` distance```.

The desired output for getting maximum distance values will be:

```
Genes   intA    Chr_intA    Chr_intB    direction_1 direction_2 distance
GeneA   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -3467567
GeneB   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -2884
```

And the desired output for getting minimum distance values will be:

```
Genes   intA    Chr_intA    Chr_intB    direction_1 direction_2 distance
GeneA   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -423
GeneB   P53 chr19   chr8    -   -   -40
```

I tried the methods below but the problem is that it changes negative values to positive values as well as the shape of the final output. How can I solve these two minor things? Thanks.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(Genes, intA) %>% summarise(distance = max(abs(distance)))
df <- df %>% group_by(Genes, intA) %>% summarise(distance = min(abs(distance)))
```

Comment: What else do you expect if you change negative values to positive? It is fine to get absolute values but then you need to make sure which you need to calculate with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice_min` and `slice_max` to get the highest or lowest `n` (default is 1) rows by group. Since you are looking at distance, you should use `abs` to get the absolute value of the distance.

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(Genes, intA) %>%
  slice_max(abs(distance))

#  Genes intA  Chr_intA Chr_intB direction_1 direction_2 distance
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>       <chr>          <int>
#1 GeneA P53   chr19    chr8     -           -           -3467567
#2 GeneB P53   chr19    chr8     -           -              -2884
  
dat %>% 
  group_by(Genes, intA) %>%
  slice_min(abs(distance))

#  Genes intA  Chr_intA Chr_intB direction_1 direction_2 distance
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>       <chr>          <int>
#1 GeneA P53   chr19    chr8     -           -               -423
#2 GeneB P53   chr19    chr8     -           -                -40
```